# If else hiding div

Tags: symfony, if-statement, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I having a problem on hiding `div`..... All I wan't to do if the `query` is `NULL` then the `div` will not show, but if the `query` is not `NULL` the `div` will show.

**here is my code:**

```
 <?php
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('m.MemberNo')
         ->from('Membership m')
         ->where('m.EntityID = ?',$entity->getId());
         $eMemberships = $q->fetchArray();
         $ctr == 0;

       if(!$eMemberships){
       }
       else{

  ?>
<div class="largeform" style="height: 370px; width: 906px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <!--h2>Customer Cards Associated to Entity <?php echo $entity->getFirstName()." ".$entity->getLastName() ?></h2-->
    <h2>Customer Chorva <?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'CustomerassocEntity')?> <?php echo $entity->getFirstName()." ".$entity->getLastName() ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'membershipid')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'cardno')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'carduid')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'type')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'membershipid')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'rebatepercent')?></th>
                <th style="color: gray"><?php echo $gfUtil->transLang($_SESSION["lang"], 'activationdate')?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        <?php foreach($eMemberships as $eMembership):?>
        <?php
            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('c.id as cID, c.CardNo as cNo, c.CardUID as cUID, c.Type as cType, c.Status as cStatus, c.MembershipID as cMID, c.RebatePercent as cPercent, c.ActivationDate as cDate')
                ->from('Card c')
                ->where('c.MemberNo = ? AND c.Type = 4',$eMembership["id"]);
                $eCards = $q->fetchArray();
        ?>
        <?php foreach($eCards as $ecard): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $eMembership["id"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cNo"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cUID"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cType"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cMID"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cPercent"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ecard["cDate"] ?></td>
                <!--?php $ctr++; ?-->
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <!--?php if($ctr==0): ?-->
         <!--tr><td colspan="7"><?php  echo "No Record(s) found!"; ?></td></tr-->
        <!--?php endif ?-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

by the way I'm using symfony/doctrine..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check that array returned from fetchArray() has no elements instead

Comment: sorry dude I can't get you.. can you elaborate your answer thanks a lot.

Comment: It possible that eMemberships will be an empty array instead of null

Comment: yes you have a point there dude... so if it is empty, you mean to say it has also an elements?

There are no returned value from that array... what should I do? it gives me a headache.... i just want to remove that dive if there are no data..

Comment: use if(count($eMemberships )==0)